# JQuery click attr('src') return Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The images loads from ko.observableArray

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: images">
<li>
    <div class="photo">
        <h2></h2>
        <img data-bind="attr:{src: '/images/'+path}, click: $root.addImageUrl">
    </div>
</li>
```

After click on the image i want to get image src and add it to another ko.observableArray
I have following script

```
self.addImageUrl = function () {
    var src = $("img",this).attr('src');
    self.selectedImages.push(src);
};
```

But returns Undefined.

Comment: I think, the selector $("img",this).attr('src'); is wrong. Try $(this).attr('src'); to get the src of the clicked image

Comment: @Egor you shouldn't adding answer in your question, you should apply acceptable  answer, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong to use `this`. In `addImageUrl` function `this` is not element. I can suggest you to use img object instead (itэы not explicitly passed to function):

```
self.addImageUrl = function (img) {
    var src = '/images/' + img.path;
    self.selectedImages.push(src);
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jTxJ/)

Answer (score 1):

The selector `$("img",this).attr('src');` is wrong. 
Use `$(this).attr('src');` to get the src of the clicked image.

Comment: `this` in knockout function is not an element, it's context of passed object.